# Best View Widget option to input a quantity

Tags: android, input

I am planning to create a rate convertor for food recipes. The user has to introduce the quantity of some food and then select the unit (gr,kg,mg,cl...).
First of all I think in seekbar, but as the quantity could be infinite the seekbar doesn't make sense.

The best approach I can think of is: <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>[EditBox]</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>[Select unit(gr,Kg)…]</kbd>

What do you think is the best option? Do you have any tip or advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: some of this belongs as a comment, but I don't have the rep yet.

Can the amount really be infinite? For example, I've never seen a recipe with 100kg of flour in it. There's probably a reasonable limit of some kind, and that might give you the ability to simplify the UI element.

Also, why two separate boxes? Why not just have them input the amount and unit in the same box and then parse the quantity. The separate unit of measure selector introduces two additional clicks which are basically unnecessary. As a user I would be thinking of the quantity and unit of measurement as one thing. You could do something with simple help text:

[image]

Comment: strToDate is a function to do this with dates like "2 weeks" or "three days".  Works like a charm.  It's not trivial though to capture all of the use cases.  Test alot.